# can not invert the axis when calling pandas.Series.plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

```
axes=plt.subplot(111)
axes.invert_xaxis()    # not inverted
ts.plot(ax=axes)
# axes.invert_xaxis()  # inverted
plt.show()
```

Why can not it invert the axis before calling pandas.Series.plot, but it can do it after calling? since my program is complicated, the figure is embedded in tkinter, lines on the axes are drawn via pressing buttons, so to invert the axis before calling plot is optimal. What is convenient for it?

Answer (score 0):

I just did some research on `matplotlib.plot`

when you first define `axes` and reverse x-axis, it did reverse the x-axis.

```
axes=plt.subplot(111)
print(axes.get_xlim())
# (0.0, 1.0)
axes.invert_xaxis()
print(axes.get_xlim())
# (1.0, 0.0)
```

But when you call `ts.plot(ax=axes)`, the function overwrites the `x_axis` value in object `axes` with new `ts`'s axis value:

```
ts = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
ts.plot(ax=axes)
print(axes.get_xlim())
#(0.0, 2.0)
```

what you have done to `axes` before have been overwritten.

It just likes the example below:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x[0] = 4
print(x)
#[4, 2, 3]
def func(l):
    l[0] = 1
func(x)
print(x)
#[1, 2, 3]
```

you did do some change on the list, but the `func` also did the some changes on the list and covered your changes.

Comment: I know it must operate the axes object. Thanks. But it is really unnecessary to re-invert the axis or overwrite anything.